# Jquery Validate plugin only works with HTML form tag

Tags: jquery, forms

For .net reason I need to canghe the html form tag  and use an `div id="etg_p_print_form"` instead  of `form name="etg_p_print_form"`

**`function calc_total() {` is not working as it works only with form tag.**

With form TAG on name

```
function calc_total() {
        f = document.etg_p_print_form;
        t = document.etg_p_print_form.total_price;
}
```

With div tag on id

```
 f = $('form')[0];
 t = $('#total_price')[0]
```

**HTML**

**with FORM**

```
<form name="etg_p_print_form" class="form-calculator">
```

**with DIV**

```
<div id="etg_p_print_form" class="form-calculator">
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/zMAz6/10/

Comment: validate plugin is meant to validate forms only. It wont work on divs

Comment: I use the validation for another form.

Comment: what doesn't work? If you switch to a div this needs to change for one: $('form.form-calculator input') to $(".form-calculator") or $("div.form-calculator input") other than that you need to be more specific as to what you expect to happen and what doesn't happen.

Comment: function calc_total() { is not working as it works only with form tag.

Comment: @DD77 update the calc_total function to work with a div. You can't navigate through a div exactly the same way you can a form to it's inputs.